# A Null Refrence Exception while working with Properties

Tags: .net, vb.net, properties, nullreferenceexception

Do you see where the problem lies? Code will run from frmFacility and will shift into UserControl:

```
Public Class frmFacility
Private primaryBaseDay As Date
Private isClassPrimaryView As Boolean = False
Friend WithEvents BookCtrl As ucBookCtrl2
Public Property Primary_BaseDay() As Date
    Get
      Return primaryBaseDay
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Date)
      primaryBaseDay = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Property IsOnPrimaryView() As Boolean
    Get
      Return isClassPrimaryView
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
      isClassPrimaryView = value
    End Set
  End Property
Public Sub GotoDay(ByVal theDay As Date)
    Primary_BaseDay = theDay
    IsOnPrimaryView = True
    BookCtrl.GotoDay(theDay)
End Sub
End Class

   Imports frmFacility
Public Class ucBookCtrl2
Public Sub GotoDay(ByVal whichDay As Date, Optional ByVal MainFacilityUsed As String = "")
Dim facilityForm As frmFacility
If facilityForm.IsOnPrimaryView Then
        moDoBooking.m_BaseDay = facilityForm.Primary_BaseDay
        moDoBooking.m_CurrentDay = whichDay
        ShowDay()
        RaiseEvent ChangeOfDay()
End Sub
End Class
```

At the line `If facilityForm.IsOnPrimaryView Then`, I get a `NullReferenceException`. Do you know the reason?

Also, I cannot create a new instance of the `facilityForm`, since I need to work with  its singleton, although when I add a new instance of `frmFacility`, the `IsOnPrimaryMode` is set to `false` while it should be set to `true` in the `gotoday` sub from `frmFacility`.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't set the `facilityForm` to anything, you simply declared a variable of type `frmFacility` and called it `facilityForm`. When you attempt to call `facilityForm.IsOnPrimaryView`, `facilityForm` is still `null`.

Comment: OK, Thanks anna but the thing is when I create a new instance it is not set to true while it should be, what is wrong really?

Comment: @amir You probably have to pass your existing instance of `frmFacility` into that method or expose it through a property on the same class.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually working with the facilityForm singleton. You will have to store it somewhere. Maybe a `Public Class` with a `Shared test as New frmFacility`.

The Form can not have the IsOnPrimaryView property yet because it is not instanciated. It is practically `Nothing`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set IsOnPrimaryView property as shared, otherwise you will get NullReference exception.